# Download Azure function files through azure-sdk-for-go

Tags: go, azure-functions, azure-sdk

I'm trying to find a way to download Azure function files through azure-sdk-for-go.
Basically something similar to theirs portal.
Will appreciate any help.
[image]

Comment: It's not in the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do it is to use Azure [Kudu API](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki]).
Each Azure function App have a publish profile which can be fetched from the SDK or the site itself.
From the publish profile we get a (key, secret) pair to use in the [Kudu zip api](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API#zip)